# Java 8 Grouping by Multiple Fields into Single Map

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private LocalDate c;
    private int d;
}
```

I have a list of `Foo` objects that I want to group by `a`, `b`, and `c` and produce a map. Here's what I have so far:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> test = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getA, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getB), Collections.unmodifiableList())));
```

But that itself is wrong. I don't know how to groupby multiple fields but still produce a `Map<String, List<Foo>>`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 1:** If I have the following Foo's:

```
{"Test", "Test", "10/02/2015", 5}
{"Test", "Test", "10/02/2015", 4}
{"Test", "Test", "10/02/2015", 3}
{"Test", "Test", "2/02/2015", 5}
{"Test", "Potato", "2/02/2015", 5}
```

Then it should group to:

```
{"Test", "Test", "10/02/2015", [5, 4, 3]}
{"Test", "Test", "2/02/2015", 5}
{"Test", "Potato", "2/02/2015", 5}
```

My original post was misleading in what exactly I wanted but basically it needs to group by a, b, d and produce a list of d. I know I'll probably have to create a new class to store them in like so:

```
public class FooResult {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private LocalDate c;
    private List<Integer> d;
}
```

How can I group and map to a new class like shown above?

Comment: What is the `String`-key in the map supposed to be? The `a`?

Comment: Maybe you want a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<LocalDate, List<foo>>>>` instead?

Comment: @marstran yes the key should be a.

Comment: @tobias_k no I specifically don't want that. I just want a simple `Map<String, List<Foo>>`

Comment: If the (only) key is `a`, then how are they supposed to be grouped by `b` and `c`?

Comment: You **can't** perform a group-by operation on 2 fields and expect to get `Map<String, List>` back

Comment: Requirements clarified above, sorry for the confusion

Comment: concat a,b and c (formatted) and use that as key??

Comment: The expected result you have in the post is not a map - the String key is not unique. The key of your map has to be some composite type containing a, b and c.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your expected output shows 3 keys (per entry), yet you're asking for 1 key. Please explain.

Comment: I suggest you still use that map-in-a-map-in-a-map approach as an intermediate step and then build your `FooResults` from that.

Answer (score 2):

As a group by multiple fields is not implemented you have to use a composite key consisting of values from `a`, `b` and `c`. With that key the collect operation can be used like this with the `Collector#of()` factory method.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> result = foos.stream().collect(Collector.of(
    HashMap::new,
    ( map, foo ) -> {
        map.compute(foo.a + "_" + foo.b + "_" + foo.c, (key,list) -> {
            if(list == null){
                list = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            list.add(foo.d);
            return list;
        });
    },
    ( map1, map2 ) -> {
        map2.forEach(( k, v ) -> {
            map1.compute(k, (key, list) -> {
                if(list == null){
                    list = v;
                } else {
                    list.addAll(v);
                }
                return list;
            });
       });
       return map1;
    }
));
```

Comment: Instead of using `compute` for all purposes, it’s simpler to use `computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value)` for the accumulator and `merge(k,v, (l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2); return l1; })` for the combiner. But note that you are just reinventing the `groupingBy` collector; `groupingBy(foo -> foo.a + "_" + foo.b + "_" + foo.c)` does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use intermediate `Map` with a key that aggregates fields `a`, `b` and `c` from `Foo` class and `List<Integer>` value that collects all `d` field values.. In below example I have created `MapKey` class - a helper class that aggregates those fields and implements `hashCode` and `equals` methods so it can be used as a key in a `HashMap`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

        final List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(
                new Foo("Test", "Test", LocalDate.parse("10/02/2015", dateFormat), 5),
                new Foo("Test", "Test", LocalDate.parse("10/02/2015", dateFormat), 4),
                new Foo("Test", "Test", LocalDate.parse("10/02/2015", dateFormat), 3),
                new Foo("Test", "Test", LocalDate.parse("02/02/2015", dateFormat), 5),
                new Foo("Test", "Potato", LocalDate.parse("02/02/2015", dateFormat), 5)
        );

        List<FooResult> result = foos.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(foo -> new MapKey(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c), Collectors.mapping(Foo::getD, Collectors.toList())))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> new FooResult(entry.getKey().a, entry.getKey().b, entry.getKey().c, entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static final class Foo {
        private final String a;
        private final String b;
        private final LocalDate c;
        private final int d;

        Foo(String a, String b, LocalDate c, int d) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
        }

        int getD() {
            return d;
        }
    }

    public static final class FooResult {
        private final String a;
        private final String b;
        private final LocalDate c;
        private final List<Integer> d;

        FooResult(String a, String b, LocalDate c, List<Integer> d) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FooResult{" +
                    "a='" + a + '\'' +
                    ", b='" + b + '\'' +
                    ", c=" + c +
                    ", d=" + d +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static final class MapKey {
        private final String a;
        private final String b;
        private final LocalDate c;

        MapKey(String a, String b, LocalDate c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof MapKey)) return false;

            MapKey mapKey = (MapKey) o;

            if (a != null ? !a.equals(mapKey.a) : mapKey.a != null) return false;
            if (b != null ? !b.equals(mapKey.b) : mapKey.b != null) return false;
            return c != null ? c.equals(mapKey.c) : mapKey.c == null;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = a != null ? a.hashCode() : 0;
            result = 31 * result + (b != null ? b.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (c != null ? c.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then as you can see you can do your transformation is 6 lines of code. The output of this program is following:

```
FooResult{a='Test', b='Potato', c=2015-02-02, d=[5]}
FooResult{a='Test', b='Test', c=2015-02-02, d=[5]}
FooResult{a='Test', b='Test', c=2015-10-02, d=[5, 4, 3]}
```

I've also made `Foo`, `FooResult` and `MapKey` immutable - this is always a good choice when you have to deal with stream transformations. You don't want to have any side effects during stream manipulation and immutable objects guarantee that.